# Using a loop to render JSX is giving me syntax errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, render, jsx

I am trying to render a repeating block in JSX using a `for` loop, and this is how I went about it.

In my component, but outside my render, I have my function as follows:

```
tenCards = () => {

    let block = [];

    /* Outer loop for container */
    for(var i = 0; i < 11; i+2){
        block.push(
            <div className="container">
                <Card id={i}/>
                <Card id={i+1}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return block;
}
```

And inside my render I am simple calling `{this.tenCards()}`. I was getting a syntax error, and now it compiles successfully, but the page never loads, and I get the

> aw snap chrome error.

Am I just doing the for loop wrong?

After switching i+2 with i+=2 it does move one step forward, but JSX says property values have to be expressions or text, so the id={i} is not working and putting quotes around it makes it a string and for some reason I can't escape the quotes with `\`.

I fixed the property error that it needs to be a string like this

```
<Card id={`${i}`} />
```

So that way JSX knew it was a JavaScript expression that gave a number between 0 & 10 and later `` quotes were placed around the number to make it a string. If you know a simpler way to do it please comment, but this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the property error that needs to be a string like this:

```
<Card id={`${i}`} />
```

So that way JSX knew it was a JavaScript expression that gave a number between 0 & 10 and later `` quotes were placed around the number to make it a string. If you know a simpler way to do it please comment, but this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the `for` loop. Replace `i + 2` with `i += 2`.

Comment: That did fix it but JSX says prop values have to be expressions or text so the id={i} is not working and putting quotes around it makes it a string and for some reason I can't escape the quotes with \

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
const numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
const cards = numbers.map((i) =>
    <div className="container">
        <Card id={i}/>
        <Card id={i+1}/>
    </div>
);
```

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components

Comment: Your method is working but running into the same eventual problem where it says: prop values have to be expressions ror text so the id={i} is not working and putting quotes around it makes it a string and for some reason I can't escape the quotes with \

Comment: I think that would be related to the `this.props` of the component, not related to the loop in question. Can you post the rest of the component?

Comment: The card component is mainly using the number passed into the id prop to pull from an api out of 10 results in a results array something like this: data.articles[this.props.id].title                                                             
That way if I render ten cards they each pull from a new result the api throws me